# Change css "display" property using animejs

Tags: css, display, anime.js

I'm trying to change a div element's "display" property from `none` to `block` using animejs, but nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
function marker_hover() {    
    anime({
        targets: '.battery',        
        display: 'block',
        duration: 250,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });
}
```

the idea is to reveal an element when another element is hovered(this function is assigned to an onhover event)
element is defined as:

```
<div class="battery">TEST</div>
```

CSS:

```
.battery{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: The `display` property cannot be animated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of AnimeJS is simplifying Vanilla JS gesture of CSS.
Thus CSS in order to create a fadeIn animation you would need to edit opacity and not display.

so your css should be

```
.battery {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And JS

```
anime({
  targets: '.battery',        
  opacity: '1',
  duration: 250,
  easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
  begin: function() {
    document.querySelector('.battery').style.display = 'block';
  },
});
```

Comment: `opacity: hidden;` ? Is this a joke? Since when is this a valid CSS `opacity` property value?

Comment: Instead of using `opacity: hidden`, use `0` as `opacity` does not have `hidden` property value.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, and also to clarify @user3491125's answer; Animejs can only animate properties that have numerical values. So to change your display value, write the regular js code in the **begin** callback, which is triggered once when the animation begins.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30020044)

Comment: Explaining what resolved your issue could help other users understand what they have to do :)
You could also share your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing that you can try. After searching in the doc for a long while I think (as David said) it can't process any string value directly. I don't know why they didn't add any features like that, but it can be done with opacity:0 if you are looking for a smooth transition.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg id="art" width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>

<script>
var tl = anime.timeline({
  easing: 'easeOutExpo',
  duration: 750
});

// Add children
tl
.add({
  targets: '#art',
  translateX: 100,
})
.add({
  targets: '#art',
  translateX: -100,
})
.add({
  targets: '#art',
  translateX: 100,
opacity:0,
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use any more tricks you need to use callback.